# execute javascript after focused on an element

Tags: javascript

I need to run `execFunc();` not only when the user moves onto the next field, but also runs when the user remains focused on the same field for 5 seconds.

```
$('input[name="email"]').bind('blur', function () {
 execFunc();
});
```

Comment: How about you *not* do this? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timer = null;
$('input[name="email"]').blur(function(e){
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  execFunc();
}).focus(function(e){
  timer = setTimeout(execFunc, 5000);
});
```

If you're doing form validation, there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: It's not validation, just wanting to save their email in case that's the last thin they do and abandon their shopping cart

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
$('input[name="email"]').bind('blur', execFunc).bind('focus', function() {
    setTimeout(execFunc, 5000);
});
```

If the function isn't idempotent and you must execute it only once, you can do:

```
var execFuncHasExecuted = false;
function execFunc() {
    if (execFuncHasExecuted)
        return false;
    execFuncHasExecuted = true;

    // ... remainder of implementation
}
```

Comment: this will execute execFunc twice if the user blurs the field before the 5 secs is up.

Comment: It should be noted that VoteyDisciple's first code sample utilizes [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: @sholsinger, so does the OPs example.

Comment: @zzzzBov Which is why I specifically included a caution about that and one possible resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice

```
var g_timeout = null;

$('input[name="email"]')
      .blur(function () {
           execFunc();
      })
      .focus(function(){
           if (g_timeout) clearTimeout(g_timeout);
           g_timeout= setTimeout(execFunc, 5000);
      });
```